# Remove 'previous', 'next' and 'done' button at html form

Tags: iphone, html

When I use a form in my website and then visit it on my iphone I get the 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Done' bar on top of the keyboard.

[image: 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Done']

Because I want to save as much space as possible and I don't like the look of this bar I would like to remove/not show it at all. Is this possible without using javascript?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No this is not possible. You can't nor should you change this behavior because it's something user expect.

Comment: Is it at least possible to make the 'Done' button submit the form instead of hiding the keyboard? (I would understand if it isn't)

Comment: No, you can't access any of those buttons.

Comment: I am using a webView in an iPhone App and I would also happily remove those buttons, because within my application these buttons don't have to be there and my user shouldn't even notice that he is using a HTML-backed view...

Comment: I don't agree at all with your comment- Why should this never be changed? Because the all omnipotent Apple decided to place it there? Oh, c'mon. If I have a form with a single input box and a "GO" button- why should I have a prev/next area that's dimmed out, and one silly "done" button when the native GO would suffice?