# In browser, using React-DOM, how can I manipulate the default IOS keyboard?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, keyboard, textarea

I'm specifically looking to get rid of the autocomplete bar and "prev, next, done" bar when in safari.

I've tried

```
<textarea 
  id="lyric-input" 
  autocomplete="off" 
  autocorrect="off" 
  autocapitalize="off" 
  spellcheck="false" 
  type="text" 
  value={this.state.value} 
  onChange={
      (event) => {
          this.setState({value: event.target.value})
      }
  } 
  onMouseUp={this.editWords} 
  onKeyUp={this.selectWord} 
  placeholder="Type lryics here..."/>
```

I still am getting

[Iphone Simulator Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfLlq.png)

I've checked this on an iphone5 and iphone6 as well as emulators.

If anyone knows of ways of further manipulating the IOS software keyboard WITHOUT making a native app and using the  `UITextField` and `UITextView`classes.

Comment: Doesn't look possible. Answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939487/ios-keyboard-without-prev-next-done-button-for-html-input-field and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920952/remove-previous-next-and-done-button-at-html-form

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my a few hours of googling @JeffMcCloud